# Yii2 - Get an app URL without params

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have no idea how to get a full url to my app web folder in Yii2.
The following rules:

```
<?=Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl();?><br>
<?=Yii::$app->homeUrl;?><br>
<?=Yii::$app->getHomeUrl();?><br>
<?=Yii::$app->request->url;?><br>
<?=Yii::$app->request->absoluteUrl;?><br>
<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?><br>
<?=Yii::$app->request->scriptUrl;?><br>
<?=Url::to();?><br>
<?=Url::to(['site/index']);?><br>
<?=Url::base();?><br>
<?=Url::home();?><br>
<?=Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl();?><br>
```

returns:

```
/yiiapp/web
/yiiapp/web/
/yiiapp/web/
/yiiapp/web/en/reset-password-request
http://website.com/yiiapp/web/en/reset-password-request
/yiiapp/web
/yiiapp/web/index.php
/yiiapp/web/en/reset-password-request
/yiiapp/web/site/index
/yiiapp/web
/yiiapp/web/
/yiiapp/web
```

when I need to get the (absoluteUrl is the closest one here):

```
http://website.com/yiiapp/web
```

I could probably combine one of the results with some $_SERVER var… but is it a solution?

Comment: please clarify what your after. Like show the url you are expecting and what the controller/view is of that page.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this post is quite old but I want to answer it anyway.
To get a full URL to your app web folder in Yii2 you can try these three options:

1. `Url::to('@web/', '');` returns `//website.com/yiiapp/web/`
2. `Url::to('@web/', true);` returns `http://website.com/yiiapp/web/`
3. `Url::to('@web/', 'https');` returns `https://website.com/yiiapp/web/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createAbsoluteUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#createAbsoluteUrl%28%29-detail) method or [`yii\helpers\Url::toRoute()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#toRoute%28%29-detail) to generate absolute urls. [`yii\helpers\Url::to()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail) also can be used look at the documentation. E.g. `<?=Url::to(['site/index'], true);?>` should output *http://website.com/yiiapp/web/site/index*. If you need to get root url to your app, try `\yii\helpers\Url::to('/', true);`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but probably the most clean way to get base URL of your app is to use [`Url::base()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#base()-detail):

```
Url::base(true);
```

Most of methods in `Url` helper allows to you specify `$scheme` argument - you should use it if you want to create absolute URL (with domain).

> The URI scheme to use in the returned base URL:
>
> - **false** (default): returning the base URL without host info.
> - **true**: returning an absolute base URL whose scheme is the same as that in yii\web\UrlManager::$hostInfo.
> - **string**: returning an absolute base URL with the specified scheme (either `http`, `https` or empty string for protocol-relative URL).